# Tabset in html rmarkdown

Tags: html, r-markdown, sections, tableofcontents, tabbed

I am working on a html document (readthedown theme) of rmarkdown and i would like to create several ".tabset" but :

I would like that the tabset's content appears only when i click on it in the table of content and not appears ones after ones directly on the body of doc.

For example, when i am in the first tabset, and i'm going through the several sub tabset, i don't want to seing the next tabset on content of the page.

in my situation i have :

```
# Title1 {.tabset .tabset-fade}
## sub title a {.tabset .tabset-fade}
## sub title b {.tabset .tabset-fade}
## sub title c {.tabset .tabset-fade}

# Title2 {.tabset .tabset-fade}
## sub title d  {.tabset .tabset-fade}
## sub title e  {.tabset .tabset-fade}
## sub title f  {.tabset .tabset-fade}
```

and if i am in the content of sub title a or b or c i dont want to see the content of Title2 when i arrived at end of these sections, like this :

[Readthedown Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XudXG.png)

Here, the content of sub section b has been selected and i saw only the content of sub section b and not other content

i've already tried several methods like .tabset-dropdown, .active but it doesn't works

is it possible ?

Thanks for your help :)

Max

Answer (score -1):

I just solved my problem. For me, it was due to the outdated bundled Pandoc version in Rstuido. I just followed the [instructions](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html) and installed the Pandoc.

I used the same Readthedown theme.